# Getting error-Invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: xpath

I am beginner in Selenium.Please help.

Here I am giving xpath of login button

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String exePath = "C:\\Users\\CAREER POWER\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\CAREER POWER\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*button[@id='u_0_n']")).click();
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().forward();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.facebook.com");
     driver.navigate().refresh();
     driver.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a wildcard to match *any* tag name. You should use `*` or real tag name, but not both. So try to choose one from below expressions:

```
"//*[@id='u_0_n']"
"//button[@id='u_0_n']"
```